# regular expression for file name - limit name size and file extention

Tags: java, regex, icefaces

I need regular expression for icefaces input file component, file name length should be less than 15 characters and have proper extention. I wrote this, but it fails:

> ^.{0,100}.+.(asf|avi|csv|pdf|doc|docx|dot|eml|gif|htm|html|idx|tif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|mp3|mpg|msg|ppt|pptx|pst|rtf|txt|wav|wma|xls|xlsx|zip"+
>   "|ASF|ASI|CSV|PDF|DOC|DOCX|DOT|EML|GIF|HTM|HTML|IDX|TIF|JPG|JPEG|BMP|PNG|MP3|MPG|MSG|PPT|PPTX|PST|RTP|TXT|WAV|WMA|XLS|XLSX|ZIP)

Comment: You could avoid repeating the lowercase and uppercase version of your known extensions by using the `i` "case-insensitive" flag.

Comment: Try `^(?!.{16}).*\.(?:YOUR_EXTENSIONS)$` (or as Aaron suggests, `(?i)^(?!.{16}).*\.(?:YOUR_EXTENSIONS)$`) (note that the backslash in a Java string literal must be doubled)

Comment: If you want max 15 characters, why do you set upper limit to 100? And what's with all the dots? `.{0,100}` = 0 to 100 of any character. `.+` = 1 or more of any character. `.` = exactly one of any character. In all, that means 2 or more of any character. No upper limit of 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> file name length should be less than 15

This can be achieved with a positive lookahead `(?=.{0,15}$)`. However, with a negative lookahead, this condition can be expressed more elegantly.  We can use `(?!.{16})` negative lookahead anchored at the start that means that the match should be failed if there are 16 characters.

To shorten the pattern, you may also use the [embedded flag expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html) `(?i)`.

So, you may use

```
(?i)^(?!.{16}).+[.](?:asf|avi|csv|pdf|doc|docx|dot|eml|gif|htm|html|idx|tif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|mp3|mpg|msg|ppt|pptx|pst|rtf|txt|wav|wma|xls|xlsx|zip)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BJPddS/1).

Note that `.+` will match any 1+ characters other than linebreak symbols, as many as possible, up to the last `.` followed with one of the extensions.

A bit shorterned version with `?` quantifiers:

```
(?i)^(?!.{16}).+[.](?:asf|avi|csv|pdf|docx?|dot|eml|gif|html?|idx|tif|jpe?g|bmp|png|mp[3g]|msg|pptx?|pst|rtf|txt|wav|wma|xlsx?|zip)$
```

Comment: The numbers in the lookaheads might require an adjustment (I assumed equal to or less than 15). If the length can't be 15, they should be changed to `(?!.{15})` (and `(?=.{0,14}$)`).

Comment: ^(?!.{16}).*\.(?:YOUR_EXTENSIONS)$ working perfectly, for icefaces component

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple by using a look ahead for the extension to keep the main part simple:

```
^(?=.*\.(?i)(asf|avi|...etc...|zip)$).{,14}$
```

Comment: *file name length should be less than 15 characters*. Your expression allows at least 19.

Comment: @wik interpret that as meaning the non-extension part

Comment: @wik OK. I think you were right. Still think I have the KISS solution :)

Comment: Yes, I know, we belong to different regex schools. I believe in precision. You choose simplicity. Let OP and others decide what expression is best.

Comment: @Wik I like precision too and I am always keen to learn, so what is imprecise about my regex?

Comment: After all your amendments, our regexps are the same in functionality. However, checking length before the actual pattern makes a regex engine fail faster in case the string is shorter/longer than expected. So, my approach is still preferable.

Comment: @wik I think I understand what you meant now: It's true that I favour brevity and readability over "performance" (as long as the performance has the same time complexity). For example, here it is unlikely that filenames will be "huge" so any "performance" difference will not be realistically measurable/noticeable.